# ¿Por qué un entero con un cero inicial da error en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estoy intentando lee un entero con un cero inicial. El problema es que me devuelve un error de sintaxis. **Mi objetivo es que me reconozca dicho cero  inicial.**

Escribí un código para reorganizar un número de tres cifras de modo que lo concatene del mayor al menor y lo devuelva.

El código:

```
def op3(num1):
  try:
    cadena = str(num1)
    
    if len(cadena) == 3:
      cadena = list(cadena)
      numeroList = list()
      for i in range(len(cadena)):
        mayor = cadena.index(max(cadena))
        numeroList.append(cadena[mayor])
        cadena.pop(mayor)

      numMayor = int(numeroList[0] + numeroList[1] + numeroList[2])

      rpta = numMayor

    else:
      rpta = "Opción 3: ¡ERROR! Escriba un número positivo y/o de tres (3) cifras"

  except:
    rpta = "Introduzca valores numéricos"

  return rpta

op3(081)
```

No he podido encontrar la manera de que reconozca el cero inicial

¿Podría alguien aconsejarme al respecto?

Answer (score 1):

## Introducción al problema

Te devuelve un error de sintaxis simplemente porque **Python como lenguaje no permite que un entero empiece por cero** para evitar problemas con el lenguaje `C` (Python está construido sobre `C`), puedes verlo en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals) y más detalladamente en [PEP3127](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/) así si intentamos:

```
print(081)
```

**Nos devuelve:**

```
    print(081)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Recalco que he dicho un **entero** ya que un `float` si nos sería permitido

```
print(081.92)
```

**Salida:** `81.92`

Antiguamente en Python 2 empezar un número con ceros significaba que dicho número estaba en base octal (en vez de decimal), es decir números del cero al ocho. El 0 era una advertencia para Python en el que se le indicaba que **estabas trabajando en base octal.** Si se quiere conseguir lo mismo en Python 3 hay que añadir un zero y una `o`, Ejemplo:

```
print(0o7, ',', 0o11)
```

Salida: `7 , 9`

Obviamente si ponemos los número ocho o nueve, nos dará un error de sintaxis, puesto que el ocho y el nueve no existen en base octal.

## Solución

La solución es pasar los números como `str` (string) o como `float` (Aunque para `float` debes hacer cambios en tu función). Así no te saltarás la regla de python que impide empezar a los enteros por cero:

```
print(op3("081"))
```

**Salida:** `810`

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que un numero que comience con 0, Python entiende que ese numero será Octal. Sin embargo el formato completo es `0oDIGITOS`, y debido a que [no está correcto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620174/1545868), te lanza el mensaje de error.

```
>>> 11
11
>>> 011
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted
>>> 0o11
9
```

Por otro lado, si es válido usar las facilidades que da el lenguaje, no hay que usar ningún ciclo para hacer lo que quieres. Existe el método [sort()](https://docs.python.org/es/3/howto/sorting.html) que ordena un iterable ascendente o descendentemente.

La entrada **debe ser una cadena** y no un número. Y de todas formas, otro lenguaje eliminaría el 0 a la izquierda si fuese un entero.

```
>>> num = "482"
>>> sorted(num)
['2', '4', '8']
>>> sorted(num, reverse=True)
['8', '4', '2']
```

Con lo anterior, puedes construir una función que haga eso:

```
def op3(strnum):
  rpta = sorted(strnum, reverse=True)
  return ''.join(rpta)
```

Answer (score 1):

Como te han explicado en otras respuestas, poner 0 delante de un entero confunde al *parser* de python que espera entonces un número en octal.

Pero creo que el problema aquí es más de fondo... Aún si python admitiera ese cero inicial tal como tú esperabas... ¿en qué se diferenciaría el entero 081 del entero 81? ¿O de 000081? Todos ellos son en el fondo el mismo valor: 81.

Por tanto aún si pudieras poner ceros delante de un número, ya que éstos en el fondo no tienen valor, la función recibiría en `num1` el número 81. Por tanto al pasarlo a cadena con `str(num1)` obtendrías `"81"` por más que hubieras puesto ceros por delante al pasarle el parámetro.

### Solución

La solución es no añadir los ceros a la izquierda cuando pasas el parámetro, sino cuando conviertes `num1` en cadena. Eso puedes conseguirlo si en vez de:

```
    cadena = str(num1)
```

usas:

```
    cadena = "{:03d}".format(num1)
```

El formato `03d` indica que quieres que en la conversión a cadena el número se trate como un entero (eso es la `d`) que ocupe 3 cifras (eso es el `3`) y que en caso de que ocupe menos se rellene por la izquierda con ceros (eso es el `0` delante del `3`).

Así, si invocas a la función con `op3(81)`, el parámetro `num1` valdrá 81, pero la cadena resultante será `"081"`. Y si la invocas con `op3(7)`, la cadena saldrá `"007"`.

Por cierto que si invocas con un número de más de tres cifras, ej: `op3(1234)`, la conversión a cadena dará `"1234"` (pues en ese caso el formato `03d` no puede ser aplicado porque no se puede dejar en tres cifras). De modo que tu función seguirá imprimiendo en este caso el error pertinente, es decir, seguirá funcionando correctamente.

Comment: Entiendo su punto, pero la cuestión es la siguiente: Poner un cero dentro del código y no en el parámetro inicial sería suponer que el usuario va a escribir si o si un cero dentro del número de tres enteros; pero ¿y si el usuario no necesita o no quiere poner un cero?

Lo que yo necesito es un código que me permita reorganizar el orden de **cualquier** número de tres cifras de la mayor a la menor, incluso si, en ocasiones, dicho número de tres cifras empieza en cero.

Comment: Entonces claro, para un computador 081 puede ser lo mismo que 81; el meollo del asunto es que para una persona a la que le piden _un número de tres cifras_, 081 es diferente de 81 en tanto que _081_ tiene tres cifras y _81_ tiene sólo dos.

Comment: Entonces, en mi cortísima experiencia quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de hacer que python reconozca el cero inicial como un dígito así como el _1_, el _2_, el _9_, etc.

Comment: Si el número se lo vas a pedir al usuario lo tienes más fácil, ya que la forma de leer la entrada del usuario es mediante `input()` y esta función no devuelve un número, sino una _cadena_. Por tanto si el usuario escribe 081, `input()` devolverá la cadena `"081"`. Así que si pasas la cadena leída a tu función, ya no necesitas convertirla en string dentro de ésta, ya todo funcionará como quieres (salvo, claro, que quizás el usuario escribe algo que no sea un número, como "Hey", pero aún así tu función lo hará bien gracias al try/except)